# Using a counter in a loop within a loop = problems in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, loops, counter

Hi thanks for your help.

Im a total noob at excel but I have been teaching myself due to my research needs
I created this basic code by adapting it from the youtube channel ExcelVbaIsFun

```
Sub ZipCodeSum2()

Dim dbsheet As Worksheet
Set dbsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lr = dbsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
SelRow = Selection.Row
'zip code
zip = dbsheet.Cells(SelRow, 2)

For i = 2 To lr 'change lr to 3 for testing purposes
Cells(i, 3).Select

 For x = 2 To lr 'change lr to 10 for testing purposes
    If dbsheet.Cells(x, 2) = zip Then
        counter = counter + dbsheet.Cells(x, 1)
    ActiveCell = counter
    End If

 Next x

Next i

End Sub
```

The problem is that for the first 'i' "outer loop" runs fine and the sum function works well. However, in the next 'i' it adds the result of the first 'i' sum and then adds the second 'i' sum to it as well. So if the zip codes are the same, it basically results in the second 'i' being double the result that I want.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

[sample of my worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH7Ea.png)

Comment: It sounds like you need to include an `Exit For` once you find a match or switch to `application.match` to get the first match only.

Comment: Is there a reason why SUMIF or SUMIFS is not a better solution?

Comment: @YowE3K - You know me... always looking for the easy way out.

Comment: To answer your specific question, stick a `counter = 0` before `For x = 2 To lr`, but that won't get your code working correctly - you will be writing the same value to every cell in column C at the moment, because you are setting `zip` outside your `For i` loop.  (But there is a possibility it will be writing to a different sheet entirely because you don't qualify which worksheet `Cells(i, 3)` refers to.)

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for your suggestion! How would I add that to the code? Also for the SUM function, I looked into but I couldn't find a good skeleton to do what I can with a 'Counter'.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for your comment! I will try that and get back to you guys

Comment: @YowE3K You were right in that every cell in column c is the same. I also qualified Cells(i,3) to dbsheet.Cells(i,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `counter` to be reset before the inner loop is executed, initialise it before entering that loop:

```
Sub ZipCodeSum2()
    Dim dbsheet As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim SelRow As Long
    Dim zip As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim counter As Currency
    Dim x As Long

    Set dbsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lr = dbsheet.Cells(dbsheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lr 'change lr to 3 for testing purposes
        'zip should be set inside the "For i" loop
        zip = dbsheet.Cells(i, "B").Value
        counter = 0
        For x = 2 To lr 'change lr to 10 for testing purposes
            If dbsheet.Cells(x, "B").Value = zip Then
                counter = counter + dbsheet.Cells(x, "A").Value
            End If
        Next 
        dbsheet.Cells(i, "C").Value = counter
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

But this can be simplified to:

```
Sub ZipCodeSum2()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            .Formula = "=SUMIF(B:B,B2,A:A)"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Or you could just place the formula

```
=SUMIF(B:B,B2,A:A)
```

into cell C2 in Excel and copy it down.

Comment: Amazing! This code works well! I used your first suggestion as I didn't understand anything about your second sugg. The last sum formula I can't use as my database has over 300,000 entries and it would take me forever. Thank you!

Comment: Now im going to study this code until i realized what you did :)

Answer (score 1):

In C2 try,

```
=sumifs(a$2:a2, b$2:b2, b2)
```

Fill down as required.

If you only want the last instance of a value to show the sum total then,

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2, A2)=COUNTIF(A:A, A2), SUMIFS(A$2:A2, B$2:B2, B2), TEXT(,))
```

Comment: Lol my database sometimes has 300,000 or more but thank you though!

Comment: If you think that nested loops utilizing worksheet cell references will be faster than SUMIFS then you would be mistaken. Even variant memory arrays would be hard-pressed to beat it. However, I will throw you an upvote just because you think 300K rows is a lot of data.

Comment: sorry if I sounded condescending, I just never worked with this amount of a data. Im also getting into a problem with the speed of the calculation, it crashes a lot. I will try SUMIFs next and see if that fixes it.

Comment: btw, anything over 50K rows and you should be saving as an .XLSB (Excel Binary) workbook. btw², it is my default save as mode.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried the SUMIF function but its counterintuitive for me as it gives me a lot of values inbetween, when I would rather just have repetitive values and just use another macro to delete the repetitions, qualifying it to match both zipcode and monetary data.

Comment: The .XLSB helped a lot with speed! I didn't even knew what that extension did before Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm, the excel did not accept the code as you suggested and it made suggestions to "fix it". After fix it ended up looking like the pic i attached to your answer.

Comment: You replaced my `=` with a `*`.

Comment: Then it doesn't return a value. Could it be cuz its not in column 3?

Comment: In C2 as above.

Comment: Interestingly, it returns only certain values. It looks like blank,blank,blank, #, blank, blank, blank, #